# How to add dictionary values from a list in a for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of dictionaries called test:

```
test = [
    {
        'age': 15,
        'country': 'Canada'
    }, 
    {
        'age': 21,
        'country': 'Denmark'
    }, 
    {
        'age': 35,
        'country': 'USA'
    },
    {
        'age': 55,
        'country': 'Canada'
    }
]
```

To each dictionary I would like to add a new key called 'degrees' and a value from the following list:

```
listy = [0,1,1,2]
```

My desired outcome would be the following:

```
[{'age': 15, 'country': 'Canada', 'degrees': 0},
 {'age': 21, 'country': 'Denmark', 'degrees': 1},
 {'age': 35, 'country': 'USA', 'degrees': 1},
 {'age': 55, 'country': 'Canada', 'degrees': 2}]
```

I have tried:

```
listy = [0,1,1,2]
for num,n in enumerate(test):
    n['degrees'] = listy[num]
```

but that throws an error... I think there is a simple solution but I am stumped.
I appreciate any help - Thanks in advance!

Comment: `n['degrees'] = listy[num]`. In the future, please include your full backtrace when requesting debugging help.

Comment: your code worked for me. what error are you getting?

Comment: This works for me. I am not able to understand what your problem is?

Comment: @jordanm solved it, I had the wrong brackets... can't believe I missed it

Answer (score 6):

You can use `zip` to simultaneously iterate over the dictionaries and the new values, which is a little faster than indexing on each iteration

```
for each_dict, value in zip(test, listy):
    each_dict['degrees'] = value
```

Since lists and dictionaries are both mutable, then modifying `each_dict` will update the list.